# n-th bit of the binary representation

Tags: string, binary

I have a problem that asks 
"find the K-th bit of the binary representation of an integer N"
 where 0 <= K <= 31. 
The answer states that when N=1 K=0 , the k-th bit is 1
and also
when N=2 K=1 , the k-th bit is 1 as well. How is this so?

Answer (score 0):

The little endian binary representation of 1 is 0000 0000 0000 0001 and the little endian binary representation of 2 is 0000 0000 0000 0010.

Comment: @joey: It can mean either. Here, you can tell from the example.